# LWC - Download ContentDocument on button click

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

Which is the best way to download a ContentDocument by the button's onclick event?
(Available also in community)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the trick using navigation:

In HTML

```
<lightning-button label="Click me" onclick={download}></lightning-button>
```

In Javascript

```
download() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0692w000000MmSyAAK?operationContext=S1'
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Does this work for community users also?